# Stop tap has no effect on water flow

Tags: plumbing

I am dealing with the fixture in the photo.  There are 2 water inlets, one for the washing machine, and one for a dish washer.  The bottom valve opens and closes the water flow to to the bottom pipe.  However, the top valve seems to have no effect whether open or closed and nothing but a drip comes out of this top pipe.  Everything was working a few days ago until i shut off the top valve to fit a new dishwasher.

The turning mechanism of the top valve seems very light and I am thinking perhaps it could have broken loose from the valve so that the valve is shut regardless of the position of the handle.  Is this feasible?

Would appreciate any pointers regarding the waterflow problem and how to resolve.

Thanks.

[image: Top tap does not affect water flow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the valve has failed or that something is blocking it.  At this point, your best bet would probably be to turn off the water upstream and remove the valve.  Watch for anything that might have come loose from somewhere and clogged it up.  You should also be able to shine a flashlight in one end and see the light looking in the other.  When the valve is open, you see some light, and closing the valve darkens the side opposite the flashlight.  If moving the valve has no effect, you would likely benefit from replacing it.

Comment: Thanks, that's basically what I was going to try.  It just seems strange as i read gate valves fail but ball valves are generally much better.  Anyway, off the plumber merchants later.  will see if replacing it helps...